# Find object using property from another object as key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React component i have array and object:

```
   topPlayers: [
     {Name: 'User1', ...},
     {Name: 'User2', ...}
   ]

   players: {
     User1: {},
     User2: {},
     ...
   }
```

Both of them i have in state, and in my view i want show list of topPlayers with additional info about them from `players` array.

```
render() {
  return(
   {Object.keys(this.state.topPlayers).map((key, i) => (
         <div key={i}>
                <span>{this.state.topPlayers[key].Name}</span>
                <span>{this.state.topPlayers[key].Points}</span>
                <span></span> 
              </div>
            ))}
  )
}
```

and in last `span` i want bind field from array of players like `this.state.players[this.state.topPlayers[key].Name]`, but this does not work. I'm so new in React, so i can not understand what i did wrong.

I would be grateful for the help or any tips.

Comment: Object.keys on array returns array indexing (numbers). Just map the whole array.

Comment: @Tholle i left comment under your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `topPlayers` state is just an array, so you can use `map` on that directly. You can use the `Name` of a top player as a key directly on the `players` object.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    topPlayers: [{ Name: "User1" }, { Name: "User2" }],
    players: {
      User1: { description: "foo" },
      User2: { description: "bar" }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { topPlayers, players } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {topPlayers.map((player, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <span>{player.Name}: </span>
            <span>{players[player.Name].description}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I got an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined`.

Comment: But it's work with your example, and this is so strange. Maybe in my case this is does not work, 'cuz i set data to state on componentDidMoun and when view is rendering, they are does not exist?

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk Yes, if you load `topPlayers` and `players` at different times, that error might occur.